# Working with both landscape and portrait document

Tags: c#, itext

I'm currently writing a pdf api. there is a method that merges selected pages with different orientation, into one document. At runtime, if the selected page is in landscape I want be merge like that, but currently everything is displaying has portrait.

I have viewed several post online, but none of them has helped.

This is what I currently have:

```
public static void MergePDF(string source, string destination, PageCollection pages) {
        try {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(source), null);


            Document doc = new Document();
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(destination, FileMode.Create));
            doc.Open();
            PdfContentByte contentByte = writer.DirectContent;

            foreach (Page page in pages) {
                float width = reader.GetPageSize(page.Number).Width;
                float height = reader.GetPageSize(page.Number).Height;


                PdfImportedPage pdfImportedPagepage = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, page.Number);

                doc.NewPage();
                if (width > height) {
                    doc.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
                } else {
                    doc.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4);
                }
                iTextSharp.text.Rectangle psize = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(page.Number);

                switch (psize.Rotation) {
                    case 0:
                        contentByte.AddTemplate(pdfImportedPagepage, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
                        break;
                    case 90:
                        contentByte.AddTemplate(pdfImportedPagepage, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(page.Number).Height);
                        break;
                    case 180:
                        contentByte.AddTemplate(pdfImportedPagepage, -1f, 0, 0, -1f, 0, 0);
                        break;
                    case 270:
                        contentByte.AddTemplate(pdfImportedPagepage, 0, 1.0F, -1.0F, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(page.Number).Width, 0);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

            }

            doc.Close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is there a special reason why you use `PdfWriter` for this task instead of `PdfCopy`? `PdfCopy` simply would use the page as is, including its dimensions and orientation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per MKL sugguestion, this worked:

```
 Document doc = new Document();
            PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(doc, new FileStream(destination, FileMode.Create));
            doc.Open();

            foreach (Page page in pages) {
                doc.NewPage();
                copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, page.Number));
            }
```

thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider reading (the freely available) [chapter 6](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf) of [iText in Action — 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/) for more information on how to use iText to manipulate PDFs.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (width > height) {
                    doc.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
```

Youve told your program that if it is wider than it is tall (landscape) then it should be rotated to be portrait. Simply remove that rotate segment

```
                switch (psize.Rotation) {
                    case 0:
                        contentByte.AddTemplate(pdfImportedPagepage, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
                        break;
                    case 90:
                        contentByte.AddTemplate(pdfImportedPagepage, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(page.Number).Height);
                        break;
                    case 180:
                        contentByte.AddTemplate(pdfImportedPagepage, -1f, 0, 0, -1f, 0, 0);
                        break;
                    case 270:
                        contentByte.AddTemplate(pdfImportedPagepage, 0, 1.0F, -1.0F, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(page.Number).Width, 0);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
```

This part is calculating the orientation of the page to know how much to rotate it, if you remove this all pages will be imported exactly as is. If you leave it all will be rotated to be vertically positioned

Comment: I have tried it without that line. I have even tried this: doc.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4_LANDSCAPE); still shows has portrait

Comment: I removed the switch statement and did this contentByte.AddTemplate(pdfImportedPagepage, 0, 0); doesn't help either

Comment: to clarify, you removed the switch statement AND the if that checks if width is greater than height?

Comment: Yes I did, and it is still being rotated.

Comment: something tells me it is to do with the 0's and the -f's that addTemplate comes with in the examples, i dont fully understand them yet